# Is there any research done on ideal proctoring algorithms?

Tags: exams, cheating

I am a grad student TA and I proctor exams. I want to know, what is the best way to proctor? As in, paths to take while walking, when to stand, when to walk, etc.

Is there any rigorous studies on what catches the most cheating? How does the algorithm change for larger or smaller classrooms?

I am interested in scientific studies, not anecdotes. Are there any rigorous studies for this?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, surely proctoring exams is on topic for academia.SE. I want to keep it scientific and not just anecdotal. This actually seems like a very interesting problem in optimization, too.

Comment: The way you asked this question might be out of scope ("shopping question"). Even so, I think it is on-topic. Personally, I don't see the need in making a science out of catching cheats.

Comment: The determination of such an algorithm is certainly a math (or perhaps CS, etc) problem, but since you're asking about such results and how to apply them, rather than how to determine such an algorithm, I think it is perfectly appropriate for Academia SE.

Comment: @ian_itor What do you mean it's a shopping question? Aren't shopping questions like "what program should I choose" etc.?

Comment: I think asking for studies/publications on a specific topic could be viewed as "shopping"

Comment: As a graduate assistant course instructor, I had two students who turned in identical homework assignments once.  I was convinced there was something fishy going on, but my supervisor and I decided we didn't have clear proof.  He arranged for a special, large classroom shaped like an L for the final exam.  The students who were under scrutiny were assigned seats that were so isolated from others, cheating would have been just impossible.  They both failed the final.  One ended the course with a failing grade and the other with a D.  I personally think that preventing cheating is more ...

Comment: ... important than catching students in the act.  Also, I can say that I found the spaciousness of that large classroom made the proctoring MUCH easier. // I'm sorry, this isn't scientific, so I'm not sharing it as an answer, but I hope my experience is a little bit helpful.

Comment: Network interdiction is a mathematical problem with characteristics similar to yours. The name "David Morton" comes to mind. He used to be at UTexas and is now at Ohio State. You should be able to find pointers to some of his research. (As @aparente001 hints, however, this might be more trouble than it's worth.)

Comment: Unpredictability may be key to preventing cheating. If people taking the exam can't predict when you are going to walk past them, it may be harder to e.g. pick a time to use a cell phone. If you follow any fixed path or plan, it gets easier.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - My proctoring days were long before cell phones.  I suppose that cell phones have changed everything....  I wonder if there's a simple detector that would notice electronic devices.  I wonder if mirrors would help.  Also, I wonder if there are ways to design exams such that there would be less of a need for quick data retrieval.

Comment: Guys, you are missing the beauty of the challenge. The ultimate question is - is there a scientific approach to this  - something that gives a principled answer to: how do I best prevent cheating and catch those who commit it.

Comment: "Is there any rigorous studies on what catches the most cheating?" - It seems there is some disagreement on the merits of this question, and I tend to side with the search for creative answers, but this was the one part of your question that bothered me. I suspect the way to catch the most cheating would be the most covert observation possible - essentially baiting your students to teach. I would strongly disagree that this is the optimal solution. Without any studies in mind, a game theory approach is probably going to get you further than a graph theory traveling salesman approach.

Comment: I proctor tests for high school science teams and one thing I do is require them to turn off their phones and place them face down on the desk in front of them. That way I can see them, and know they aren't using them. If you don't advertise this before the test, no one is going to bring a decoy phone either.

Comment: Put a video camera at each desk, and another in the ceiling over each desk, and another under each desk, and three more in each bathroom stall. Don't tell the students about the cameras. Hire a team of hundreds to scour through the videos. It'll take years, and you'll probably land in jail, but if there's cheating, you'll catch it.

Comment: I would post an answer, but I don't want to use anecdotes to support my point. Having been a student I know which students cheat. You have to do profiling and focus your attention on those students. If you have international students in the body, due to cultural reasons Chinese and Middle Eastern students are the most likely to cheat (Not trying to imply that all of them do). It is very commonplace in their country. Also do it on student by student case. If someone doesn't show up for class and shows up for an exam, pay attention. If someone looks nervous, fidgeting pay attention.

Comment: There is no scientific method as to how to walk around an exam room. I think the best thing you can do is look at the students giving the exam. Also if possible scramble the seating or have pre-assigned seating. Also consider Survivor Bias in any research of this type. Because students that get caught cheating are usually the ones doing it wrong. The ones doing it right, will never get caught. Hence this data will yield nothing interesting to you.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you can formulate the problem mathematically in a way which can lead to some well-known optimisation problem.

However, I think the mathematical model you described is very restricted and the solution is not likely to work very well in practice, even if you find it. Your model only includes moving and observing a certain part of a room - plain and simple. However, in practice, cheating is prevented not only by someone who "polices" the situation. It is a more complex process, which includes some aspects of ethics, culture, community values, etc. Creating a proper culture within your School / University is much better way of preventing cheating, than walking around students following a super-optimal path prescribed by a supercomputer.

Also, the efficiency of a proctor depends not only on their path through the room, but on a lot of psychological  factors, e.g. how this person is perceived by students. A lazily walking person will not be very efficient in preventing cheating whatever the path is. A really "scary" proctor (with heavy looks, etc) can prevent all cheating sitting on their chair in a corner of the room. There is much more factors to this problem than trajectory only, and that's why I don't think the model you suggest is very useful for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at *A Comprehensive Literature Review on Cheating*, Simha and Cullen, and *Detecting and Preventing Cheating During Exams*, Yee and MacKown.  I feel like I only scratched the surface.  Not really sure why you need help with the literature search....